# sql fetching special character from DB2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, db2

Name = McDonald's | # 176 address lane

Name = KFC | 67 address lane

condition :

The special character (.,/-!@#$^&.....) with name and address should be printed.

So, the name McDonald's and # 176 address lane should be printed and the rests of the names and addresses without the special characters should be eliminated

Expected Output :

McDonald's # 176 address lane

Comment: Why did you tag this with SQL Serer **and** DB2? Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `LIKE` for comparison. It will allow you to use `%` (or another character) as a wild card for string comparison.  If you need more help after looking in the manual, please explain what part you did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `TRANSLATE`:

```
SELECT Name, Address FROM mytable WHERE Name <> TRANSLATE(Name,'                 ', '(.,/-!@#$^&.....)') OR Address <> TRANSLATE(Address,'                 ', '(.,/-!@#$^&.....)')
```

The second parameter for `TRANSLATE()` is a string consisting of all characters you want to trap. The first parameter is a string of blanks the same length as the second parameter.

If any characters are found in `Name` or `Address` that match any characters in the second string, a changed value will be used for the comparison. By comparing against the original values, you'll catch rows that have the special characters.